# Examples of Poor RESTful design

Tags: api, rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

I am looking to understand the consequences of bad RESTful design. For instance, I have heard that it is poor practice to use verbs in REST endpoints instead of nouns.  I would like to know the consequences of employing verbs in this case.

Comment: This question is probably too broad for Stack Overflow.  You might want to rephrase this to be more specific, for example "Why is it poor practice to use verbs in REST endpoints?" or "Why is X considered poor RESTful design?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, the consequence of not following a RESTful design is that you're not implementing a RESTful service. That's all.

For now, I don't know of any atomic explosion after publishing a non-RESTful service.

BTW, if your documentation states that your API is RESTful and you don't use URIs as resource identifiers, you use verbs in URIs (that is, they're not pointing to resources but operations) and you don't follow many more rules to consider an API as *RESTful*, you're defeating the purpose of a RESTful API since it should be built on top of *convention over configuration* paradigm, and stating *I'm RESTful* while *you're not RESTful* isn't a convention: it's an anti-convention.

You can still implement a non-RESTful API, but you'll need to teach your clients how to work with it as no one is developing an API like yours.

Summary:

- REST is a paradigm. You can go with it or go your own way.
- There's no direct technical consequence if you don't go with RESTful API excepting that your audience won't understand your API design *by default*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This definitely gives something for me to think about :)

Comment: Here's what [R.T. Fielding](https://roy.gbiv.com/) has to say about [calling an api RESTful](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).